# Cannot set property "death" of undefined

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties

So I was browsing the eloquent javascript book and I am really struggling to understand the mechanism behind a program inside it. The program simply is to search within a list of `paragraphs` for `newborn` cats and `dead` ones and add them to an object (the object has `name`, `birthdate`, `mother name`) and in case of death the object gets an extra `death` property. I wrote it from scratch because I understood how the functions work together to provide this program but I have been struggling for hours to add the `death` property to the object.

the code is pretty long as you can see but I'd really appreciate explaining.

```js
var firstParagraph = "=>born (14-02-2014) <mother freska>: pinky, brain";
var secondParagraph = "=>born (15-12-2016) <mother jasmina>: jarvis, daisy";
var thirdParagraph = "=>born (23-03-2014) <mother jan>: oreo, leo";
var fourthParagraph = "=>died (10-01-2015): tom";
var fifthParagraph = "=>died (19-02-2016): brendal";

var paragraphList = new Array(firstParagraph,secondParagraph,thirdParagraph,fourthParagraph,fifthParagraph);

//Creating the functions that will help build the program

//A function that picks up the cat names and put them in array.

function catNames(paragraph) {
 var colonSeparator = paragraph.indexOf(':');
 return paragraph.slice(colonSeparator + 2).split(", ");
}

//A function that searches for both born and dead cats.
function searcher(context,pattern) {
 return context.slice(0, pattern.length) == pattern;
}

//A function that creates a cat record (details about cats)
function catDetails(name, birthDate, motherName) {
 return {name: name, birthDate: birthDate, mother: motherName};
}

//A function that adds the cats to the set.
function addCatToSet(set, names, birthDate, motherName) {
 for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  set[names[i]] = catDetails(names[i], birthDate, motherName);
 }
}

//A function that adds the death status to a certain cat.
function deadCats(set, names, deathDate) {
 for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  set[names[i]].Death = deathDate;
 }
}

// A function that extracts mother cat name 
function getMother(paragraph) {
 var startOfIndex = paragraph.indexOf("<mother ") + "<mother ".length;
 var endOfIndex = paragraph.indexOf(">");
 // console.log(endOfIndex);
 return paragraph.slice(startOfIndex,endOfIndex);
}

//A function that gets cat date (either birth or death) 
function getCatDate(paragraph) {
 function numberAt(start, length) {
  return Number(paragraph.slice(start, start + length))
 }

 return new Date(numberAt(14, 4), numberAt(11, 2) - 1, numberAt(8, 2));
}

//Main function that populates the set properly


function catFinder() {
 var cats ={};
  cats.Samo = catDetails("Samo", new Date(25,12,2012), "unknown");

 function catHandler(paragraph) {

  if (searcher(paragraph,"born")) {
   addCatToSet(cats, catNames(paragraph), getCatDate(paragraph), getMother(paragraph));
  }

  else if(searcher(paragraph,"died")) {
   deadCats(cats, catNames(paragraph), getCatDate(paragraph));
  }
 }

 for (var i = 0; i < paragraphList.length; i++) {
  var paragraphs = paragraphList[i].split("=>")
  for (var j = 0; j < paragraphs.length; j++) {
   catHandler(paragraphs[j]);
  }
 }

 return cats;

};

console.log(catFinder());
```

```html
<body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="eloquent-js.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: You should debug it first and narrow the problem down.

Comment: What is with `set[names[i]]` ? You haven't defined any variable named `set`, I think you need to do something like this: `names[i].Death = deathDate;` instead of `set[names[i]].Death = deathDate;`. The same goes for the other instances where you use `set[...]`

Comment: @Titus `set` is the first parameter of `deadCats`

Comment: `tom` and `brendal` have to be born before they can die ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s8m46xv0/))

Comment: @Andreas Oh, I see it now. I'm not sure how I've missed that.

Comment: @Andreas thank you a lot that did the trick but it shows Invalid Date both on Death property and birthDate property. What am I doing wrong with the getCatDate function?

Comment: nvm. I solved it already. thanks for the help.